# Slow API Calls and Cloudflare Warnings when Hosting Express API on Render.com

Tags: reactjs, performance, sqlite, express, cookies

I have developed an application consisting of a React-based client and a server API using Node.js, Express, and SQLite for the database. The server API is hosted on Render.com.
The problem is that the API calls in my application are significantly slow, with an average response time exceeding [10 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66dTg.jpg), making it cumbersome to load the necessary data on the client side. Interestingly, when I run the API locally, the requests are completed much faster, with an average response time of [1.5 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIBDs.jpg). This discrepancy suggests that the issue lies in the hosting environment or the interaction between the client and server parts.
Additionally, when the client makes HTTP requests to the hosted API, I encounter numerous warnings in the Firefox console related to Cloudflare cookies being rejected (Render.com utilizes Cloudflare as its underlying infrastructure). I'm not sure if this is related to the api being slow. Specifically, I receive two types of warnings:

1. `Cookie “__cf_bm” has been rejected for invalid domain.` - This appears to be a [protection mechanism against bots](https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/get-started/reference/cloudflare-cookies/#__cf_bm-cookie-for-cloudflare-bot-products).
2. `Cookie “_cfuvid” has been rejected for invalid domain.` - This warning seems to be related to [rate limiting rules](https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/get-started/reference/cloudflare-cookies/#_cfuvid-for-rate-limiting-rules).

I have already attempted some solutions, but the issues persist. Here are the steps I have taken so far:

- In the client, I have parallelized all the API requests using Promise.all().
- I have tried switching from using the Fetch API to Axios for making the HTTP calls, including the `withCredentials: true` option in every requests headers.

This is the function that makes all the requests when loading the page:

```js
export async function getData(hanzi: string): Promise<LoaderData> {
    const hanzisPromises = [...hanzi].reduce((acc: Promise<HanziResult>[], cur: string) => {
        return acc.concat([getHanzi(cur), getComponents(cur), getRadical(cur), getWords(cur)]);
    }, []);
    const [word, sentences, ...hanzisResults] = await Promise.all([
        getWord(hanzi),
        getSentences(hanzi),
        ...hanzisPromises,
    ]);
    let hanzis: HanziData[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < hanzisResults.length; i += 4) {
        const slice = hanzisResults.slice(i, i + 4);
        hanzis.push({
            hanzi: slice[0] as Hanzi,
            components: slice[1] as Component[],
            radical: slice[2] as Radical,
            words: slice[3] as Word[],
        });
    }
    return {
        word: word,
        sentences: sentences,
        hanzis: hanzis,
    };
}
```

I am seeking advice on how to tackle these issues and improve the performance of my application. How can I make the API faster and eliminate the Cloudflare warnings? Are there any alternative approaches or additional troubleshooting steps I should consider?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.